# Meta-language to describe types in a language-independent way for a "C-API"

Tags: language-agnostic, c-api

Is there a meta-language to describe types (structures/records, function types and their parameters ...) and constants that can be fed to a tool or that I can then write code for to create prototypes for multiple target languages? Note: (E)BNF is not even close to what I am looking for.

IDL looks closer to what I need, but those flavors I looked at didn't even cover systems that were not also object-oriented. Microsoft's M seems to be tied to .NET and the system I need it for is truly what one would usually describe as a "C-API". No fancy interface definitions or anything remotely object-oriented.

Comment: @Will: "basic flow-control" ... hmmm? Oh well. Haven't flagged them anymore. Though I disagree probably *as* strongly as the person who felt it's wrong to flag them in the linked topic. Try to apply the opposite standard to ServerFault and you see what I mean. Basic flow control does *not* imply programming. Natural language often has basic flow control, yet for English you'd probably not accept it here on SO, would you? Heck, `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian/Ubuntu has flow-control. Would it belong rather on SO or SF?

Comment: I'm more on your side, believe me.  But apparently the consensus is (now) that anything that involves something that could loosely be called scripting can be considered on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG IDL provide documents describing the mapping of IDL constructs to a number of well known languages including C:

http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/idl2x_spec_catalog.htm

Comment: yes, they are one of the IDL flavors I checked out. Thanks. You can also use Microsoft's IDL to describe a COM interface in C for example. But the thing is that I'm looking for something to describe a very simple API without the notion of objects/classes and so on. So it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Or am I missing something that is blatantly obviously and I'm still missing it?

Comment: Since this is the best answer in quite some time, I'll accept it. Though it doesn't really fit match my problem.